# Rpi4 and Ejabberd external registration

Tags: module, erlang, config, ejabberd

Some friends and I want to leave WhatsApp for good and as I've been playing around with my Rpi4 for years now, I thought I'd use that to set up an XMPP-Server for us to use, to have a secure and customizable experience.

I've tried it with ejabberd and installed it from the repo. I also tried to compile the newest version, but I get an error output every time.
It works fine so far, but it differs from what I've seen online.
My problem is, that registration from outside doesn't work at all. I can register from ejabberdctl, but that's it. On the tested clients it says "server doesn't allow registration", although I have enabled everything that says anything about registration allowance.

System: Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB)
OS: TwisterOS 1.9.6 (Based on Raspbian 32bit)
Ejabberd Version: 18.12.1-2

Config files:
Ejabberd.yml https://textuploader.com/18mqx
Ejabberdctl.cfg https://textuploader.com/18mqz

When the "mod_register" line is enabled/uncommented (or any other not by default enabled mod), ejabberdctl live gives following output: [error] Cannot load /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml: Syntax error on line 272 at position 2: did not find expected key

I am very thankful for any help, whether it's getting my current version to allow registration or compiling the current version which seems easier to work with, as all of the solutions I've seen on the internet won't work with my version.

Kind Regards,
Arokan

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You won't believe it...

The prewritten spaces in
" ## mod_register: "
seem to not have been spaces but something else, though they weren't wide as tabs but exactly as spaces.
So I deleted the spaces before mod_register: and hammered the space key myself. After that, everything worked out perfectly and other modules do as well in the same way.

tl;dr: Replace the pseudo spaces with own spaces.